# Sigmoid functions above and to the left of $\mathrm{erf}(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}x)$

Tags: functions

Wikipedia has a graph of several different sigmoid functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function. Are there any sigmoid functions that lie above and to the left of $\mathrm{erf}(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}x)$, close to the black line emphasized by the red arrows in the picture below?
[image: sigmoid functions]

Comment: What happens if you „squish“ any of the sigmoid functions?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch What do you mean by "squish"?

Comment: If you have a function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ you can consider the „squished version“ $g(x)=f(c\cdot x)$ for some $c>1$

Comment: So it seems that if I "squish", for example, tanh(x), then it moves up and to the left. Are there any examples without "squishing"?